# Simple django pass paramaters from url

Tags: django, django-views

Im getting use to using urls to pass paramaters in django and i have the following url:

```
mywebsite/view-negotiation/?negotiation=7
```

I was expecting the following rule to catch it:

```
url(r'view-negotiation/(?P<negotiation>\d+)', 'myview.views.myview')
```

but im getting a 404 page not found error. What im i doing wrong here?

Comment: the value 7 IS being passed into my view as a parameter and being used in that view. The  value passed is NOT always going to be 7, it will be any integer.

Answer (score 0):

@karthikr given url pattern is fine to match with your url

```
 url(r'^view-negotiation/(?P<negotiation>\d+)/$', 'myview.views.myview')
```

and try this to access parameter from your view

```
 def myview(request, negotiation):
     #negotiation is the parameter catch form url 
     #i.e nagotiation is a variable that having 7 or any other intiger passed by url
     #other stuff goes here
```